# PHP OOP only accessing first line of text file

Tags: php, oop

I am doing an assignment for school, and I am having an odd problem. The object that I have created only accesses the first line of a text file we are using. This is highly problematic for me because if I build a database and can only use the first line, well, so much for usefulness.

My instructor and I both can't figure out why this problem is here, and we have worked on this for over a week.

Here is the text file:

```
003345, Pauline, Sampson, Admin, 14.96
012345, Mike, King, Manager, 20.47
123456, Pete, Smith, Accountant, 25.53
345678, Mary, Jones, Accountant, 32.53
456789, Mary, King, Manager, 18.35
777999, Caroline, Baxter, Nurse, 27.45
```

Here is my start HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Modify1.html</title>
 <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css"  />
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Weekly Pay report</h1>
 <form action="modify1.php" method="post">
  <table>
   <tr><td>Employee ID 1</td><td><input type="text" name="id1"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Employee ID 2</td><td><input type="text" name="id2"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Employee ID 3</td><td><input type="text" name="id3"></td></tr>
  </table>
  <p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Modify 1</title>
 <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css"  />
</head>
<body>
<?php
 include("inc-employee-object.php");
 
 $id1 = $_POST["id1"];
 $id2 = $_POST["id2"];
 $id3 = $_POST["id3"];

 $emp1 = new Employee();
 $emp2 = new Employee();
 $emp3 = new Employee();

 $emp1->findEmployee($id1);
 $emp2->findEmployee($id2);
 $emp3->findEmployee($id3);

 print ("<p>Weekly Pay for ".$emp1->getFirstName()." ". $emp1->getLastName().": $".$emp1->getWeeklyPay()."</p>");
 
 print ("<p>Weekly Pay for ".$emp2->getFirstName()." ". $emp2->getLastName().": $".$emp2->getWeeklyPay()."</p>");
 
 print ("<p>Weekly Pay for ".$emp3->getFirstName()." ". $emp3->getLastName().": $".$emp3->getWeeklyPay()."</p>");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my object:

```html
<?php
class Employee
{
 private $empID;
 private $firstName;
 private $lastName;
 private $jobTitle;
 private $hourlyWage;

 public function addEmployee()
 {
  $empRecord = $this->empID.",
  ".$this->firstName.",
  ".$this->lastName.",
  ".$this->jobTitle.",
  ".$this->hourlyWage."\n";
  
  $empFile = fopen("employees.txt", "a");
  fputs($empFile, $empRecord);
  fclose($empFile);
 }

 public function findEmployee($id)
 {
  $empFile = fopen("employees.txt", "r");
  $empRecord = fgets($empFile);
  $notFound = true;
  while (!feof($empFile) and $notFound)
  {
   list ($empID, $fName, $lName, $title, $wage) = explode(",", $empRecord);
   if ($id == $empID)
   {
    $this->empID = $empID;
    $this->firstName = $fName;
    $this->lastName = $lName;
    $this->jobTitle = $title;
    $this->hourlyWage = $wage;
    $notFound = false;
   }
  
   if ($notFound == false)
   {
    return 1;
   }
   else
   {
    return 0;
   }
   $empRecord = fgets($empFile);
  }
  
  fclose($empFile);
 }
 
 public function getID()
 {
  return $this->empID;
 }
 
 public function setID($empID) 
 {
  $this->empID = $empID;
 }
 
 public function getFirstName()
 {
  return $this->firstName;
 }
 
 public function setFirstName($fName)
 {
  $this->firstName = $fName;
 }
 
 public function getLastName()
 { 
  return $this->lastName;
 }
 
 public function setLastName($lName)
 {
  $this->lastName = $lName;
 }
 
 public function getJobTitle()
 {
  return $this->jobTitle;
 }
 
 public function setJobTitle($title)
 {
  $this->jobTitle = $title;
 }
 
 public function getHourlyWage()
 {
  return $this->hourlyWage;
 }
 
 public function setHourlyWage($hourlyWage)
 {
  $this->hourlyWage = $hourlyWage;
 }
 
 public function getWeeklyPay()
 {
  $this->hourlyWage = trim($this->hourlyWage);
  return number_format ($this->hourlyWage * 40, 2);
 }
 
 public function getAnnualPay()
 {
  $this->hourlyWage = trim($this->hourlyWage);
  return number_format($this->hourlyWage * 40 *52,2);
 }
} // end of class definition
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "what I'm doing wrong" - you exit the loop before you have a chance to read another line. Also, your instructor couldn't find this, within minutes? I'd look for a better instructor.

Comment: Good deal. That worked. My instructor was focusing on the wrong thing. Happens to all of us sometimes. ;) I just needed to look it over better. Thanks.

Comment: Good job on figuring this out 

Comment: I was closing the file in the wrong place, as well. That was my other problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, you will always exit on the first item due to this code...

```
    if ($notFound == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Under any condition, this will exit out of the loop and function.  This should be outside the loop and probably at the end of the function.

If you want to stop the loop once the record is found, then use `break;` something like...

```
    if ($id == $empID)
    {
        $this->empID = $empID;
        $this->firstName = $fName;
        $this->lastName = $lName;
        $this->jobTitle = $title;
        $this->hourlyWage = $wage;
        $notFound = false;
        break;   // Exit loop
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

@NigelRen is right about the loop exiting once a condition is found.  But that may be by your design and should not matter in this case as you are calling the class separately for each id.

If you look at the your text file you are missing commas in between the wage and the employee id's.  So it is only seeing the first row and not the others.

Cheers!

Comment: I think they are supposed to be separate lines of data.

Comment: What do you mean "it should not matter"? They won't be able to find employees which are not on the first line.

Comment: That looks like a comma separated text file.  He is using explode() with the comma delimiter and its jumping over the id's because he does not have a comma separating the wage from the if of the next employee.

Comment: @Joseph_J Wrong. You were misled by poor formatting of the post. I formatted it as it should be. Look again.

Comment: @Joseph_J btw, if you want others to see your comment, you `@mention` them. Had I not have this page open, I'd miss your last two comments.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - Thank you again, I did know that either.